# How do I change dtype in my neural network

Tags: python, numpy, neural-network

I am a newbie to neural networks and found this code of the neural network.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Activation function
def sigmoid(t):
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-t))


# Derivative of sigmoid
def sigmoid_derivative(p):
    return p * (1 - p)


# Class definition
class NeuralNetwork:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.input = x
        self.weights1 = np.random.rand(self.input.shape[1], 4)  # considering we have 4 nodes in the hidden layer
        self.weights2 = np.random.rand(4, 1)
        self.y = y
        self.output = np.zeros(y.shape)

    def feedforward(self):
        self.layer1 = sigmoid(np.dot(self.input, self.weights1))
        self.layer2 = sigmoid(np.dot(self.layer1, self.weights2))
        return self.layer2

    def backprop(self):
        d_weights2 = np.dot(self.layer1.T, 2 * (self.y - self.output) * sigmoid_derivative(self.output))
        d_weights1 = np.dot(self.input.T, np.dot(2 * (self.y - self.output) * sigmoid_derivative(self.output),
                                                 self.weights2.T) * sigmoid_derivative(self.layer1))

        self.weights1 += d_weights1
        self.weights2 += d_weights2

    def train(self, X, y):
        self.output = self.feedforward()
        self.backprop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    X = np.array(([0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1]), dtype=float)
    y = np.array(([0], [1], [1], [0]), dtype=float)
    NN = NeuralNetwork(X, y)
    for i in range(1500):  # trains the NN 1,000 times
        if i % 100 == 0:
            print("for iteration # " + str(i) + "\n")
            print("Input : \n" + str(X))
            print("Actual Output: \n" + str(y))
            print("Predicted Output: \n" + str(NN.feedforward()))
            print("Loss: \n" + str(np.mean(np.square(y - NN.feedforward()))))  # mean sum squared loss
            print("\n")

        NN.train(X, y)
```

Current output:

```
# for iteration # 1400
# 
# Input : 
# [[0. 0. 1.]
#  [0. 1. 1.]
#  [1. 0. 1.]
#  [1. 1. 1.]]
# Actual Output: 
# [[0.]
#  [1.]
#  [1.]
#  [0.]]
# Predicted Output: 
# [[0.01013418]
#  [0.97148752]
#  [0.97080865]
#  [0.03590563]]
# Loss: 
# 0.00076425301653189
```

I want to change this floating from 0 to 1 numbers to `int64` dtype numbers for having this:

```
X = np.array(([3, 5, 8, 10], [3, 5, 8, 10], [3, 5, 8, 10], [3, 5, 8, 10]), dtype=np.int64)
y = np.array(([3], [5], [8], [10]), dtype=np.int64)
```

What do I do for that:

1. Changed dtype from `float` to `np.int64`
2. Changed data in the lists to data I want to get (integers). Minimum int is 0 maximum 37 (included).

But it returns me the result in the 0 - 1 float range.

```
# Input : 
# [[ 3  5  8 10]
#  [ 3  5  8 10]
#  [ 3  5  8 10]
#  [ 3  5  8 10]]
# Actual Output: 
# [[ 3]
#  [ 5]
#  [ 8]
#  [10]]
# Predicted Output: 
# [[0.99999998]
#  [0.99999998]
#  [0.99999998]
#  [0.99999998]]
# Loss: 37.500000214318064
```

So I changed:

1. Changed `np.random.rand` to `np.random.randint` in the `NeuralNetwork` constructor

And it raises an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "E:/NeuralNetwork/main.py", line 54, in <module>
NN = NeuralNetwork(X, y)
File "E:/NeuralNetwork/main.py", line 28, in __init__
self.weights1 = np.random.randint(self.input.shape[1], 4)  # considering we have 4 nodes in the hidden layer
File "mtrand.pyx", line 745, in numpy.random.mtrand.RandomState.randint
File "_bounded_integers.pyx", line 1363, in numpy.random._bounded_integers._rand_int32
ValueError: low >= high
```

What should I do to replace floating numbers in the data on integer numbers for prediction?

Comment: The sigmoid output layer can only return values in `[0, 1]`, so at the very least you'll have to change the activiation function of your output layer.